# Missing parameters in AngularJS $http.get('')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, oauth

I'm working on an app which uses a Oauth authentication, I'm having some trouble with the url parameters. I've tried several different ways but my API is returning that the username and password aren't being passed to the API

Here's my code (removed the private details):

```
$http({
        url: 'http://test.com/oauth/v2/token',
        method: "GET",
        params:{
            username: user.username, 
            password: user.password,
            client_id: 'xxxxxxx',
            client_secret: 'xxxxxxx',
            grant_type: 'password'
        }
    }).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
    });
```

My API returns `Object {error: "invalid_request", error_description: "Missing parameters. "username" and "password" required"}` (error 400).

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code looks good although parts are missing. Check what is being sent via your browser developer tools. Usually F12. See if the url is being called with the query parms.

Comment: Good call, it was a really silly error, the form was email and not username... It's been a long one :P

Thanks!